# Thingsboard PE docker container can't access license server

Tags: thingsboard

I'm trying to run a Thingsboard PE docker-compose cluster (basic configuration) on an Azure Linux VM (ubuntu 20.04). The main "monolith" container shuts down after about a minute and the logs report it can't access the license server. I'm assuming it's shutting down because of license server access, and assuming the problem is that the container can't access the internet (but any advice on further troubleshooting would be appreciated).

Within the container `cat /etc/resolv.conf` returns:

```
search 1lt4eb1hmraebffqmvlsi2dp5g.px.internal.cloudapp.net
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

On the host it's:

```
nameserver 168.63.129.16
search 1lt4eb1hmraebffqmvlsi2dp5g.px.internal.cloudapp.net
```

There's no problem with internet access from the host and I can ping Google's dns servers.

I've read a lot of posts/advice on setting DNS server settings for docker containers and (separately) tried the following but the service still fails:

- Added Google dns entries to docker-compose.yml
- Added Google dns to /etc/docker/daemon.json
- Added Google dns to /etc/default/docker
- Updated /etc/resolv.conf symlink with: `sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`

It looks like I can't edit iptables on the Azure VM (but if it's possible please let me know).

If anyone has experienced the same or similar issue I'd be interested to know how you resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem, after researching further it seems the issue was actually the "options ndots:0" configuration which isn't compatible with the default host DNS config on Ubuntu 20.04. I added the below setting to /etc/docker/daemon.json and after that the containers were able to access the internet. It might be possible to limit this to specific containers by adding the setting to the service in docker-compose.yml, but I haven't tried that yet.

```
{
   "dns-opts":["ndots:1"]
}
```